# How to get everything left of a certain set of characters in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So what I have is a series of Strings all have a distinct 'MIN' in each string, for example:

```
abcdefMINjklkkase
ffffffffffMINxxxxxxxxxx
eeeMINoooooooooooooooooo
ggggggggMINkkkkkkk
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwMINiiiiiiii
```

All String sets are different length otherwise I would use LEFT function or LTRIM functions. The result I would like to get is,

```
abcdef
ffffffffff
eee
gggggggg
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

The variable, 'MIN' is consistent in all string sets just at various different lengths due to how the Strings are created.

Any help would be much appreciated!

-Maykid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  str, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'MIN.*', '') option_1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(str, r'(.*?)MIN.*') option_2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: Hello, @Mikhail Berlyant I didn't found in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_replace) what the `r` stands for, when I run my query, (`REGEXP_REPLACE(table_name, r'_.*', '') as table_name`) the result is the same with or without the `r`... Can you explain me please?

Answer (score 6):

You could use:

```
SELECT col, SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, 'MIN'))
FROM tab
```

Comment: Also works like a charm! Wish I could check both answers! Thank you again!